# UDP Socket error 10049

Tags: c++, sockets, sendto

I have a UDP server socket which can receive datagrams from clients, but is not able to send a reply back to any of them.

This is the code I use to send the buffer:

```
    SOCKADDR_IN addr;
    memset((char*)&addr, 0, sizeof(addr));

    const char* ip = "127.0.0.1";
    u_short port = 8888 // IP of the client to which the buffer is going to

    if (inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr) == 1)
    {
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
        addr.sin_port = htons(port);

        sendto(s, buffer, UDP_PACKET_SIZE, NULL, (SOCKADDR *)&addr, addrlen);
    }
```

`sendto()` returns -1 and `GetLastError()` says 10049 which means the address is not available. I'm sending and receiving the buffer on `localhost`.

Comment: You're using the [`inet_pton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function wrong.

Comment: I've used what I've found on the internet. What is the correct way of using it?

Comment: That, assuming you properly called `WSAStartup` (which we can't see), properly set the value of `addrlen` (which isn't even declared much less initialized), etc. Sorry, the holidays have left my code-clairvoyance skills a little rusty. Post *complete* code.

Comment: You mean I should use the addr I've used for binding the socket?

Comment: The lesson is don't rely on random code you "found on the internet". _READ THE DOCUMENTATION_!!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit -on SO, these days, that would be a miraculous happening.  Maybe you don't understand how SO works now.  The posters copy stuff from dubious websites or other students, get it to compile/link, (if you're lucky),  and find, of course that it does not work. Reading docs or doing any debugging is forbidden by SO rules, (I assume, since it never happens), and it's YOUR task to do all the testing, debugging and fixing for, like, 15 internet points, (if you're lucky).  It's unfortunate that on these network questions, you have to build an environment too, but so what? :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're passing a pointer to the `SOCKADDR_IN` structure as third argument to [`inet_pton`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), but if you follow the link to the MSDN reference of the function you will see that it wants an [`IN_ADDR`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738571%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure.

The [`SOCKADDR_IN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740496%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) structure has such a member, but it's not the first member in the structure, which is why you get the error; You write the address to the wrong place in the structure and the address you try to send to is not what you think it is.

The correct call would be e.g.

```
inet_pton(AF_INET, ip, &addr.sin_addr)
```

Comment: I've fixed the problem. Now it send the data but the client receives nothing.

Comment: It would be better to use the `sockaddr_in` that `recvfrom()` provides, instead of creating a new `sockaddr_in` manually. Then you would not run into this problem.